# Limit users to see only their group / product bugs in Bugzilla 3.4.4

Tags: permissions, bugzilla

In my `Bugzilla 3.4.4` (maybe others too) it seems that newly created user without any rights assigned can search thru all bugs. Is it possible to block it so that users can only see them when they are assigned to the right groups?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes , this is possible.

Administration/Products/choose the product you want to hide/press "Edit Group Access Controls"

If you set the options of the product group to Mandatory/Mandatory without marking any of the check-boxes , 
any user that is not part of that group , will not see the bugs related to it at all.

This will work in case of new users , due to the fact that new users don't get that permission automatically (by default).

TIP: instead of manually creating  group for each product , you can set Administration/Parameters/Group Security/makeproductgroups to ON

NOTE: this is true for Bugzilla 4.2.1

Comment: BTW: you can ask Bugzilla related question on the bugzilla mailing list. they help me numbe of times.http://www.bugzilla.org/support/